# 4-digit total number not displayed properly in pagination for jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

[image]

The total number (4107) is not displayed properly, there's a space in between the 1st & 2nd digit.

The jqGrid library version is 4.4.3. How to display properly? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page number in pager is formatted according to the rules of the  formatter of type integer defined into the language file. You will need to change the thousandsSeparator from space " " to empty string "".

For the 5 year old 4.4.3 version you can do this like

```
...
$.jgrid.formatter.integer.thousandsSeparator = "";
...
```

after loading the language file